# AllowHtml attribute without referencing MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, dependency-management

We have separated our business logic layer and business objects into a completely separate project/assembly. Some properties of the models can contain HTML content. In front of the business logic, we have an ASP.NET MVC web application, where users can manage the business objects.

- To allow HTML content on specific properties, we had to add the AllowHtml attribute. But we can't, because we do not want to reference System.Web.Mvc in our core project.
- Partial classes cannot be used across multiple assemblies.
- Using the MetadataType attribute is not an option, because it would cause an indirect dependency to MVC or a circular dependency between the core layer and the web application.
- Another partial solution would be to turn off request validation for the whole request, by using the ValidateInput attribute, but we want to turn off request validation only to specific properties.
- Properties are not virtual, so we can't just simply create a derived type to override the specific properties.
- We do not want to duplicate our business objects to view models with exactly the same properties and metadata.
- Overriding the model binding logic is not an option.

So, how can we indicate to the MVC model binder that we want to allow HTML content on (and only on) some specific properties, without referencing ASP.NET MVC in our business logic layer? Or, how can metadata be injected from another assembly without strong references?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why referencing System.Web.Mvc (and in turn System.Web) in your core project would be a problem?

Comment: Are you serious!? Following your pattern I could reference Windows Phone, Windows RT, WPF, Windows Forms, ASP.NET MVC... and all technologies in the separated core assemblies. There would be no point of separation at all.

Comment: You rule out the solutions - view models or including the reference. Frankly anything else is going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Referencing anything specific is absolutely not an option. Our core layer could be built even on PCL. ViewModels are, but it would take a lot of work to duplicate _everything_ and keep them consistent.

Comment: @BlueCode It was a simple question. I am trying to understand what the underlying concern is with referencing the assemblies. Re: Referencing anything else - if it has types in it that you wish to use, how else are you going to do so without referencing it (or flexing your dynamic assembly-loading-fu)?

Comment: You don't have to duplicate in view models, in fact that's pointless. View models should be just that - optimized for the views, not duplicates of business objects.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But suppose, you have a BO called Article which has a Title, PublishedDate and Content properties. The view model for editing this object would be exactly the same. All of the solutions above would solve the problem some way, but not the right way. We are looking for the right solution, which does not break dependency and normalization rules. This is the question actually.

Answer (score 8):

I had to change BindModel to the following (this builds on Russ Cam's answer) in order to check the attribute on the actual property. I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879494/159338) answer for help:

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {            
        var holderType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        if (holderType != null)
        {
            var propertyType = holderType.GetProperty(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);
            var attributes = propertyType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            var hasAttribute = attributes
              .Cast<Attribute>()
              .Any(a => a.GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(MyAllowHtmlAttribute)));
            if (hasAttribute)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelMetadata.RequestValidationEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

Comment: This is what is needed to check for the custom attribute on individual properties.

Answer (score 4):

Implement your own `IModelBinder` and `AllowHtmlAttribute` - put the attribute in your core project and the `IModelBinder` in your MVC application.

```
public class MyAllowHtmlAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

To implement the `IModelBinder`, simply inherit from `DefaultModelBinder` and add logic to turn off request validation based on the presence of your own `AllowHtmlAttribute`

```
public class MyBetterDefaultModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var allowHtmlAttribute = bindingContext.ModelType.GetCustomAttribute<MyAllowHtmlAttribute>();

        if (allowHtmlAttribute != null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.RequestValidationEnabled = false;
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Then hook up your own ModelBinder in `Application_Start` (or other startup code)

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyBetterDefaultModelBinder();
```

This logic in the custom model binder is what the `AllowHtmlAttribute` in MVC does but you wouldn't be able to use that one easily as it is intrinsically tied to ModelMetadata in MVC.

Comment: Not bad, this way we do not have to duplicate BO-s to VM-s, and all dependency rules are kept. But it amplifies the scope of allowing HTML to the model from specific properties. But if I set PropertyMetadata instead of ModelMetadata, this seems to be the best solution. Thank you. Please change it in your answer, so after some investigation, I could accept it as an aswer, if I find it right.

Comment: @BlueCode No it doesn't "amplify the scope of allowing HTML to the model from specific properties" - Unless you have defined other ModelBinders in your application, the properties of a model will each in turn be bound by the custom model binder using the `BindModel()` method, so just attribute the properties you want to allow html for. Take a look at the source code for `DefaultModelBinder` at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs

Comment: This is a great answer and checks if the custom attribute exists on the model class being bound.  For checking individual properties of the class cmour's answer does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The request validation concept that AllowHtml relies on, and the binding checks are specific to web requests. There's no separation of concerns here, they're intimately linked. So no, you can't use it without taking a reference on System.Web etc.

You rule out the (in my opinion) most correct option - View Models even though validation and binding is really a view model concept.

You can't have portable business objects with web specific binding and validation concepts.

Comment: View models seem to be the best solution from all above. But AllowHtml is the only attribute, which can not be used in that context. All validation logic can be implemented separately using the Component Model attributes and through the IValidateableObject interface. Even the data type is marked as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In the event this is still useful to someone:
I had similar requirements however my classes were generated by Entity Framework database first and so the project had used the [MetadataType] attribute extensively.

I cobbled together pieces from this question and linked questions into this solution to allow the approach to work with Metadata classes that specify [AllowHtml] (or similar)

In your Entity Framework project, define an attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class SkipRequestValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then in your metadata classes, assign this attribute to the relevant properties:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ActivityLogMetadata))]
public partial class ActivityLog
{
}

public class ActivityLogMetadata
{
    [Required]
    [SkipRequestValidation]
    [Display(Name = "Body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in your MVC project add this custom Model binder to look for these meta attributes.

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var containerType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;

        if (containerType != null)
        {
            /* Do we have a Metadata attribute class specified for the Type we're binding? */
            var metaRedirectInfo = containerType
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true)
                .OfType<MetadataTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (metaRedirectInfo != null)
            {
                /* If our Meta class has a definition for this property, check it */
                var thisProperty = metaRedirectInfo.MetadataClassType.GetProperty(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName);

                if (thisProperty != null)
                {
                    var hasAttribute = thisProperty
                        .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                        .Cast<Attribute>()
                        .Any(a => a.GetType().IsEquivalentTo(typeof(SkipRequestValidationAttribute)));

                    /* If we have a SkipRequestValidation attribute, ensure this property isn't validated */
                    if (hasAttribute)
                        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.RequestValidationEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Finally in your MVC project startup method (Startup.cs for example), replace the default model binder:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyModelBinder();
```